# If I am using a VPN and using p2p with specific open ports, does the VPN server have these ports open too?

Tags: networking, vpn, ports

If I am using a VPN and using p2p with specific open ports, does the VPN  server has to have these ports open too?

Comment: Some VPN servers do not allow open ports on their end, if the server is selectable try a different VPN server.

Comment: Yes, if you want to allow inbound traffic.

Comment: @davidgo Well how do they know which specific ports do i need opened? or do they just keep everything opened?   ..  Some applications do not support Upnp..

Comment: This question is way to vague. "They" don't.  If your VPN provider gives you your own IP address for the session, they likely choose just to allow all ports through.   Its also conceivable that they are using some kind of NAT tracking to map ports and communication to IPs.  (This technology is fairly ubiquitous now)

Comment: @davidgo ok, this cleared things up for me..